# In the doubling time formula, what does the a stand for?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$A(t) = P(2)^{t/a}$

what does the lower case a stand for?

Comment: That depends entirely on the context in which you found the formula. It looks like it's some kind of time constant, but the details can vary.

Comment: It's the doubling time.

Comment: Could we say that it's the "double life"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $a$ is the time-to-double or doubling time, analogous to the half-life of radioactive decay. Its unit is the same as the unit of time used in the problem.

At time $t=0$ the amount is $A(0)=P$, where $P$ usually stands for Principal.

At time $t=a$ the amount is $A(1)=2P$, double the initial amount.

So $a$ is the amount of time it takes for the amount to double.

Comment: thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

When the time $t$ is a multiple of $a$, the population has a nice form, as we'll see.

We can compute $$A(ka) = P\cdot 2^{\frac{ak}{a}} = P \cdot 2^{k} = 2^k \cdot P;$$ the population has doubled $k$ times. In particular, when $t = a$, the population has doubled exactly once. Thus, $a$ is the amount of time it takes for the population to double.

More generally, *every* time $t$ increases by $a$, the population doubles: you can verify that $A(t + a) = 2A(t)$.